# Unable to update due to grub problems

Tags: grub-efi

I'm trying to update Ubuntu, and each time I get an error because of the grub. I'm fairly new to Linux systems, and my attempts to update files, reinstall packages, or edit the files (undoing each time after failing to prevent breaking things further), I'm not coming to ask for help.

The error being thrown is as follows:

/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 26: /etc/default/grub: want: not found

/etc/default/grub is as follows:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debi
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... Pshhhh. That was stupid.

I was missing the backtick on line 9.

```
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debi`
```